# Information box on mouseover

Tags: javascript

Is there anyone who knows how [Voddler](http://www.voddler.com/movie/browse/) made the information box that appears when the mouse is hovering over the movie covers?

What I want is to display an information box when the mouse hovers over an image in my gallery. There is a neat solution on www.voddler.com/movie/browse and I was wondering if anyone knows how they have done? I did not realize that voddler not work worldwide, therefore, I attach a screenshot.

Comment: You should elaborate more on your question. Specifically what you want to achieve.

Comment: You should also *edit* your question, instead of posting *answers* (which you should only do if you've actually found a solution to your problem). Also, please keep in mind that SO is an international website, and we can't see the effect on Voddler, which is US-only. Try looking for something similar elsewhere, or use some other method (such as a screenshot) to impart this information.

Answer (score 1):

I can't acess Voddler (I'm outside the US) but from reading what you are asking, I would suggest using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) with [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)